# Java Swing deprecated in favor of JavaFx 2.0

Tags: java, swing, javafx, java-2d

Am I correct that Oracle has deprecated Swing and that JavaFx 2.0 is it's official replacement?

This makes sense to me because it would seem kind of goofy for oracle to maintain the development of two competing api's that do pretty much the same thing.  Yet Oracle has introduced enhancements like translucent windows, shaped windows, etc into the java 7 swing api.  I take it this may be for transitional purposes but still I'd really appreciate it if someone could clue me on what the current 'standard' or 'best practice' choice is for new applications - Swing or javafx 2.0?  Another source of unanswered questions seems to be the fate of Java 2D.  Is it worth mastering that API now that another graphics engine, Prism, uunderlies JavaFx 2.0?

Much Thanks,
Marc

Comment: Where you heard that?  Swing isn't deprecated.

Comment: @Marcelo: It hasn't been deprecated, but it's been placed into a very dark corner, one that won't likely see any major upgrades by Oracle. Though having contributed to this discussion, I think that this question is not appropriate for stackoverflow and would be best suited elsewhere, perhaps programmers.stackexchange.

Comment: *"seem kind of goofy for oracle to maintain the development of two competing api's that do pretty much the same thing."*  What, like Swing & AWT?

Comment: I found this similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318645/javafx-or-swing) although not very current, its point is you must know fundementals of Swing before going to JavaFX. So you'd have to learn both to fully grasp the concept (or alteast know Swing somewhat). Though I must say JavaFx has beautiful cascaded (CSS) UI's :). But this is not to say its deprecated. Because its not.

Comment: closed? 'we expect matters' to be such as are supportable by facts... wow.. like, 'Is it deprecated?' doesn't fit that bill?  The Java ecosystem is a complex one and to newcomers it's like a jungle at first sight.  I'm sure you have years of experience so maybe the answers here are so obvious you think the question stupid - try to remember not everyone has the benefit of your experience and knowledge. And isn't the point of this site to share that hard won knowledge?  So when a relative newcomer asks questions like whats the standard here - hows that not constructive?  Please enlighten me.

Comment: I don't think Swing will be officially deprecated, but JavaFX is the official UI Library now. See here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#6