# Using js and css in java application (Embedded browser functionality)

Tags: java, swing, twitter-bootstrap, jxbrowser

I'm developing an application using java(back end) and for front end presentation i would like to use bootstrap, css etc, it can be done easily in case of web application but i'm developing an application than is not web application(Should not run in browser). For developing gui we have swing package but doesn't support js and css. I found jxbrowser on internet should i go for it.

Comment: A complete example showing one approach is examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31574311/230513), but questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the front-end of a Java application you have a number of options.

For web based frameworks (i.e. take HTML/JS/CSS and transform into front-end for Java application) - JxBrowser is one of many available options. There are other similar frameworks too.

Java based (and not web based) -

- Swing (which in my *opinion* is somewhat [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031637/java-swing-deprecated-in-favor-of-javafx-2-0))
- JavaFX (a replacement for Swing)
- Many other UI frameworks -
  although not all maybe free.

The one you chose would depend on your requirements, licensing (i.e. free or paid), etc. There is no framework that fulfills all requirements. And from what I have seen so far (and again these are my *opinions*) it is better to go with web-based frameworks.